# Engine has minor blowby but doesn't change with more RPM

Tags: piston-ring

I opened up the oil cap and it had a steady and minor air movement outwards the fill tube. I wouldn't even say pressure, I just feel the air move. Also it doesn't change when I rev the engine. Should I even be concerned? I know a minor blowby is normal and also no there's no oil on the fill cap and no smoke coming out the tube.

Vehicle is '02 Impreza 2.5l